# Hilbert Schmidt Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

We have the integral operator:
$Lu=\int_{-1}^{1} k(x,y)u(y) \,dy$
with $K(x,y)=x+3x^{2}y+xy^{2}$ its not self-adjoint.

I have to find the $Ker(L^{*})$.

I tried to solve the equation
$L^{*}u=0\Rightarrow \int_{-1}^{1} (y+3y^{2}x+yx^{2})u(y) \,dy=0 \Rightarrow  \int_{-1}^{1} yu(y) \,dy+ x\int_{-1}^{1} 3y^{2}u(y) \,dy+x^{2}\int_{-1}^{1} yu(y) \,dy=0 $

How should i continue?

Comment: $L^*u$ needs to vanish identically. In particular, the value of $x$ can’t matter. So you have $A+Bx+Cx^2=0$ where the coefficients are functions of $y$. What does this tell you about $A,B,C$?

Answer (score 1):

You calculate $L^*$: *(Fubini applies, since $k$ is pretty good)*
\begin{align}
\langle L^*u,v\rangle&=\langle u,Lv\rangle=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1 k(x,y) u(x)v(y)\,dy\,dx\\[0.3cm]
&=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1 k(x,y) u(x)\,dx\, v(y)\,dy.
\end{align}
So
$$
L^*u(x)=\int_{-1}^1 k(y,x) u(y)\,dy=\int_{-1}^1 u+3x\int_{-1}^1 y^2u+x^2\int_{-1}^1yu.
$$
So, if $L^*u=0$ we have
$$
\int_{-1}^1u=0,\qquad \int_{-1}^1 yu=0,\qquad \int_{-1}^1 y^2u=0,
$$

Comment: So the elements of $ Ker(L^{*}) $ are the functions u(x) , which satisfy the three definite integrals? Could we find these functions?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "find"? How would you find all the functions such that $\int_{-1}^1u=0$?

Comment: thanks its very helpful :)